# How can you fill colour in specified ranges to last used row

Tags: excel, vba, row

I`ve created a function that makes use of ranges. I need fill color to lines in the ranges but i need to stop at last filled in row I`ve put the ranges in here.I`ve made a mistake not showing them to start with sorry.  Will the new code been created below work with these ranges? I`ve tried to use some codes below but not succeeding to make it work.
The ranges link to a combo box in vba form

```
            With ws

                Select Case Com.Value
                    Case ("Fill Color 1 Page Job Card")
                        Color .Range("A13:Q61")
            
                    Case ("Fill Color 2 Page Job Card")
                        Color .Range("A13:Q61")
                        Color .Range("A66:Q120")

                    Case ("Fill Color 3 Page Job Card")
                         Color .Range("A13:Q61")
                        Color .Range("A66:Q122")
                        Color .Range("A127:Q178")

                    Case ("Fill Color 4 Page Job Card")
                        Color .Range("A13:Q61")
                        Color .Range("A66:Q122")
                        Color .Range("A127:Q183")
                        Color .Range("A188:Q244")

                   
               
               End Select
                
            End With
            
            
            End Sub
```

Comment: What is your question? What is not working? Please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Problem is that it fills color rows to the bottom of the sheet. I need color rows to stop at the last filled in rows in a range. It is a colored line above the filled in rows.

Comment: How are you calling this?

Comment: If you follow the guidelines as posted previously you will get an answer within a few minutes.

Comment: What do you mean by How are calling this?

Answer (score 0):

### Color Non-Empty Rows

- If you need to color the complete rows, then in `colorNonEmptyRows` instead of each occurrence of `rng.Interior.ColorIndex` use `rng.EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex`.

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub colorNonEmptyRows()
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = defineNonEmptyRange(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Job Card Master").Cells)
    If Not rng Is Nothing Then
        'Debug.Print rng.Address
        rng.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
        Set rng = defineNonEmptyRows(rng)
        If Not rng Is Nothing Then
            'Debug.Print rng.Address
            rng.Interior.ColorIndex = 4
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Function defineNonEmptyRows( _
    rng As Range) _
As Range
    If Not rng Is Nothing Then
        Dim ColumnsCount As Long: ColumnsCount = rng.Columns.Count
        Dim RowRange As Range
        Dim bRng As Range
        For Each RowRange In rng.Rows
            If Application.CountBlank(RowRange) < ColumnsCount Then
                If bRng Is Nothing Then
                    Set bRng = RowRange
                Else
                    Set bRng = Union(bRng, RowRange)
                End If
            End If
        Next RowRange
        Set defineNonEmptyRows = bRng
    End If
End Function

Function defineNonEmptyRange( _
    rng As Range, _
    Optional ByVal NonBlank As Boolean = False) _
As Range
    If Not rng Is Nothing Then
        Dim cLookIn As XlFindLookIn
        If Not NonBlank Then
            cLookIn = xlFormulas
        Else
            cLookIn = xlValues
        End If
        With rng
            Dim cel As Range
            Set cel = .Find( _
                What:="*", _
                After:=.Cells(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count), _
                LookIn:=cLookIn, _
                SearchOrder:=xlByRows)
            Dim Num As Long
            If Not cel Is Nothing Then
                Num = cel.row
                Set cel = .Find( _
                    What:="*", _
                    After:=.Cells(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count), _
                    SearchOrder:=xlByColumns)
                Dim fCell As Range
                Set fCell = .Cells(Num, cel.Column)
                Set cel = .Find( _
                    What:="*", _
                    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                    SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)
                Num = cel.row
                Set cel = .Find( _
                    What:="*", _
                    SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                    SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)
                Set defineNonEmptyRange = .Range(fCell, .Cells(Num, cel.Column))
            End If
        End With
    End If
End Function
```